# How to programmatically set the A Address of a domain name?

Tags: php, linux, dns, server, nameservers

I have a web application which buys domains programmatically and i can also set the nameserver of the new domain from my code. This application is written in PHP and runs on Debian Linux.

The problem is that i have no idea how to set the A Address of the new domain to the ip address of my VPS(Virtual Private Server). Can anyone suggest a method to achieve this?

EDIT : My domain registrar provides APIs to set the nameserver itself but does not provide any APIs to manipulate A addresses.

Comment: How you set the nameserver depends on what APIs the company you are buying the domain from provide. How you set the A record depends on what APIs your DNS server provides (or involves you writing code to parse, manipulate and serialise the config file for it and then restart the DNS server)

Comment: Is there any easy to set up , preferably free, DNS server application available? Something i can install on another VPS? Sorry but i am a total amateur in this area.

Comment: There are several dynamic dns (dyndns) services available, free and non-free. Most of them have documentation for how to remotely configure them (usually by GET or POST special http:// URL)

Comment: @Quentin Can you tell me how this can be done? I want to connect a domain with server programmatically. I don’t care what api I will use or the hosting. I want that I have a domain and a server , I enter the details required in a form and connect them programmatically. Please tell me api’s or hosting that support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched all night and finally found a great solution to my own question.
The answer is to use [CloudFlare's Free DNS Service](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/).

You can basically host your domain's nameserver with them and they provide a [simple api](https://api.cloudflare.com/) to manipulate DNS records